# How to dispatch variable side effects in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my TypeScript project, I present the user with a branching dialogue. Text is displayed and options are presented for the user, which then enacts a new branch. Each branch may have one or more `Action`s associated with it, which have nothing to do with Redux. We'll call these `MyAction`s for clarity.

`MyAction`s are pretty versatile, you can choose the type of action and arguments to pass along with it. The action corresponds to a function registered with the `ActionParser`, which is in charge of execution these `MyAction`s.

One of the most important `MyAction`s is the `LOAD_SCENE` action, which allows the user to switch to a completely different scene. The scene is first loaded from the server and then presented to the user at the root branch of the dialogue tree. This is where the problems begin.

Normally, a scene is loaded explicitly as the result of the user clicking a button in the UI. A Thunk is dispatched, the scene is loaded, parsed and then an action is dispatched informing us of a successful load:

The way this happens is as follows:

1. The user clicks [button] in the UI
2. Button triggers mapDispatchToProps.onButtonClick
3. onButtonClick calls a function that updates the SceneParser with the new branch.
4. With the new branch selected, onButtonClick dispatches the action PARSING_START
5. SceneParser.parseActiveBranch is called, which is where actions are executed. This is where side effects happen.
6. Finally, PARSING_SUCCESS is called and SCENE_UPDATE is called to display the new dialogue and options

During step 5 the actions are processed. The LOAD_SCENE action looks like this:

```
ActionParser.register("LOAD_SCENE", async (args) => {
    if (args.scene) {
        Store.get().dispatch(loadSceneStart());
        await SceneManager.loadScene(args.scene);
        Store.get().dispatch(loadSceneSuccess(SceneManager.activeScene.author));
    } else {
        throw new Error("action 'LOAD_SCENE' requires 'scene' argument");
    }
});
```

The issues are obvious:

1. The scene UI isn't updated - I could trivially solve that by adding that here, but that could also cause unintended side effects.
2. I'm directly accessing the Store to dispatch, I don't know if that is considered a good practice, but it definitely feels wrong.

`MyAction`s are always fired off as part of the business logic. Since they can have side effects, I want the results of my actions to affect the state, but at the same time, I do not want to dispatch from the action. Here is the `dispatch` function that does it all.

```
public static onSelectOption(dispatch: Dispatch, branch: string) {
    try {
        SceneManager.selectBranch(branch); // MyActions are processed here. Side effects of MyActions may have happened.

        // These fire immediately because some MyActions may be asynchronous.
        if (SceneManager.sceneIsFinished) {
            dispatch(setMode(Mode.MainMenu));
        } else {
            dispatch(updateScene(SceneManager.dialogue, SceneManager.options));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch(setGameView(View.Error));
        dispatch(setError(error.stack || error.message));
    }
}
```

What is the best way of dealing with the side effects? How can I best handle changes to reflect in the UI and state? To be clear, my code works but I feel I am doing it the wrong way.

Comment: This is a pretty confusing question to answer. Could you please describe the relationship between the thunk and the ActionParser event listener. 

Is your Store a singleton whose get returns a redux store?

In answer to the second question, your smell is right. It isn't great to directly reference store because this impacts the portability and transparency of your code.

Comment: I know it is a confusing question to answer. I am not a native speaker so I find it difficult to explain the problem, since it is a pretty complicated one. I'll amend my question.